# Parabola and a circle touching at the vertex of the parabola

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, conic-sections

This is a problem I faced during solving my math homework. I asked my math teacher yet she didn't return to me with an answer.
I thought I could prove it algebraically but I ended up with too much parameters.
 So the approach I chose was to try and prove it on a specific parabola.
 The general problem is- Suppose we have a parabola $$y^2=2px$$ and we want to find a circle that touches the parabola at only one point $ (0,0) $.
 Also we want that circle to be inside the parabola (so $(0,0)$ will be the only common point of the circle and the parabola).

Is it possible? If it is what is the equation of the circle expressed parameterically?

Thanks!

Comment: There will probably be many circles, provided that the radius is small enough, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, this is along the lines of what you are looking for.

Firstly, I took the upper half of the circle and parabola as the curves are symmetric:

$y=\sqrt{2px}$ (the parabola) and

$y=\sqrt{r^2-(x-r)^2}$ (the circle cantered so it passes through $(0,0)$)

This equation for the circle simplifies to

$y=\sqrt{2xr-x^2}$

Setting these equal to each other and simplifying

$\sqrt{2px}=\sqrt{2xr-x^2}$

$2px=2xr-x^2$

We know from your question that $x=0$ is a trivial answer so we may divide out by $x$ giving:

$2p=2r-x$

$x=2r-2p$

We know that if the $x>0$ we have a valid solution for the intersection. However, because you don’t want there to be any intersections (apart from the trivial one) we can determine that $x \le 0$ plugging this in we get:

$2r-2p \le 0$

Which simplifies to:

$r \le p$

That means that any circle that has a radius less than $p$ will not intercept the parabola apart from at $(0,0)$

Parametrically a circle is:

$(r \sin{(t)}, r \cos{(t)})$ for $0 \le t < 2\pi$

Answer (score 2):

Say $(x-r)^2 + y^2 = r^2$ is the equation of the circle.

$y^2 = 2px$ is the equation of the parabola.

If you equate, you get $x(x+2(p-r)) = 0$.

So for $r \le p$, $(0,0)$ will be the only common point of the circles and the parabola.

Comment: Great answer. But is there an intuitive reason why when $r\le p$, $x=-2(p-r)$ isn't a solution? As in, a square-roots-only-giving-positive-values type of intuition, where you can actually tell why the negative isn't considered. Because I can see, graphing out a circle and a parabola, that there's nothing going on on the left side and that it's thus an invalid solution, but *why* we got this clearly incorrect negative value computationally, I don't understand. Could you help me out?

Comment: @harry thank you for your kind words. To your question, it is an interesting one. Why do we have extraneous solutions in many cases is an interesting point which you will find some literature on internet, if not a lot. In this case, when we are setting up the equation, we are assuming $r$ is positive and so is $p$, which means it is a parabola in the right two quadrants. But we would have solutions in the left two quadrants if $p$ and $r$ were negative. The same equation provides both. We are taking from it what we are interested in here.